# how to use the grid feature of Bootrap-4?

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-grid

I am new to the web designing and trying to learn bootstrap. I want to create a product page for that I tried to use the predefined template from - [https://www.bootdey.com/snippets/view/shop-product-detail#css](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VycWq.png)

When I used the given code it is not showing as photos and description is devided in two parts. Both are in vertical pattern.

[image]

[image]

I want it to look like this :

[image]

I want to devide the images and information in two columns and wrap the whole product details in white box.

here is the code:

```
 <div class="container bootdey">
<div class="col-md-12">
<section class="panel">
      <div class="panel-body">
          <div class="col-md-6">
              <div class="pro-img-details">
                  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/550x380/FFB6C1/000000" alt="">
              </div>
              <div class="pro-img-list">
                  <a href="#">
                      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/115x100/87CEFA/000000" alt="">
                  </a>
                  <a href="#">
                      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/115x100/FF7F50/000000" alt="">
                  </a>
                  <a href="#">
                      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/115x100/20B2AA/000000" alt="">
                  </a>
                  <a href="#">
                      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/120x100/20B2AA/000000" alt="">
                  </a>
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6">
              <h4 class="pro-d-title">
                  <a href="#" class="">
                      Leopard Shirt Dress
                  </a>
              </h4>
              <p>
                  Praesent ac condimentum felis. Nulla at nisl orci, at dignissim dolor, The best product descriptions address your ideal buyer directly and personally. The best product descriptions address your ideal buyer directly and personally.
              </p>
              <div class="product_meta">
                  <span class="posted_in"> <strong>Categories:</strong> <a rel="tag" href="#">Jackets</a>, <a rel="tag" href="#">Men</a>, <a rel="tag" href="#">Shirts</a>, <a rel="tag" href="#">T-shirt</a>.</span>
                  <span class="tagged_as"><strong>Tags:</strong> <a rel="tag" href="#">mens</a>, <a rel="tag" href="#">womens</a>.</span>
              </div>
              <div class="m-bot15"> <strong>Price : </strong> <span class="amount-old">$544</span>  <span class="pro-price"> $300.00</span></div>
              <div class="form-group">
                  <label>Quantity</label>
                  <input type="quantiy" placeholder="1" class="form-control quantity">
              </div>
              <p>
                  <button class="btn btn-round btn-danger" type="button"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> Add to Cart</button>
              </p>
          </div>
      </div>
  </section>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use d-flex class in the parent div

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container bootdey">
    <div class="col-md-12">
    <section class="panel">
          <div class="panel-body d-flex border border-5 p-2">
              <div class="col-md-6">
                  <div class="pro-img-details">
                      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/550x380/FFB6C1/000000" alt="">
                  </div>
                  <div class="pro-img-list">
                      <a href="#">
                          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/115x100/87CEFA/000000" alt="">
                      </a>
                      <a href="#">
                          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/115x100/FF7F50/000000" alt="">
                      </a>
                      <a href="#">
                          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/115x100/20B2AA/000000" alt="">
                      </a>
                      <a href="#">
                          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/120x100/20B2AA/000000" alt="">
                      </a>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-6 p-3">
                  <h4 class="pro-d-title">
                      <a href="#" class="">
                          Leopard Shirt Dress
                      </a>
                  </h4>
                  <p>
                      Praesent ac condimentum felis. Nulla at nisl orci, at dignissim dolor, The best product descriptions address your ideal buyer directly and personally. The best product descriptions address your ideal buyer directly and personally.
                  </p>
                  <div class="product_meta">
                      <span class="posted_in"> <strong>Categories:</strong> <a rel="tag" href="#">Jackets</a>, <a rel="tag" href="#">Men</a>, <a rel="tag" href="#">Shirts</a>, <a rel="tag" href="#">T-shirt</a>.</span>
                      <span class="tagged_as"><strong>Tags:</strong> <a rel="tag" href="#">mens</a>, <a rel="tag" href="#">womens</a>.</span>
                  </div>
                  <div class="m-bot15"> <strong>Price : </strong> <span class="amount-old">$544</span>  <span class="pro-price"> $300.00</span></div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                      <label>Quantity</label>
                      <input type="quantiy" placeholder="1" class="form-control quantity">
                  </div>
                  <p>
                      <button class="btn btn-round btn-danger" type="button"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> Add to Cart</button>
                  </p>
              </div>
          </div>
      </section>
      </div>
      </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: great its working.. :-) thanks.. what  if I need more space between the border and content?

Comment: use padding. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/utilities/spacing/